# Is it unhealthy to fail this bike fit and why?

Tags: bike-fit

Recently, on a beginner MTB lecture, I learned that the pedal axle should in no part of the stroke be horizontally in front of the knee. Not observing this is unhealthy for the knees.

Also, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrZBjOloChg) (btw great video) they explain a similar thing. For a "correct fit", the knee should line up with the pedal axle.

Currently I am riding my little sister's mtb. The seat is high enough, but even being slided maximum to the front, I fail the above test miserably (the seat tube is quite angled). A couple of weeks of short rides, and my knees already hurt constantly (maybe placebo effect?).

Why would having the seat too far back be unhealthy for the knees?

Comment: http://sheldonbrown.com/kops.html

Comment: I know placebo effects can be strong, but constant knee pain sounds real, and it can get a lot worse over time. Be careful, don't mess up your knees. I don't know if it's this aspect of the fit or not, but it sure sounds like your body is telling you something is wrong.

Comment: Well, one wonders how recumbent cyclists survive.  But knee pain suggests a problem.  Likely it's in part due to unbalanced muscles and gaining strength too fast.  There are leg stretches you can do to help this a lot.

Comment: The main thing is that the knee should be ALMOST (but not totally) straight at the bottom of the stroke.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, indeed I am passing the 'heels on the pedals and the legs are straight' test. Then I ride with the front of the foot over the axle (not the arch) and my legs are just a little bent.

Comment: A very likely contributor to the knee pain is simply riding in too difficult a gear.

Comment: @Vorac The KOPS test also assumes reasonable bike fit. If the bike frame is significantly mis-sized then you're not going to be comfortable and will probably struggle to pass any bike fit test.

Answer (score 2):

This principle, "Knee Over Pedal Spindle" or *KOPS* is archaic and wrong. It assumes ideal morphology.

I am about 6ft/185cm tall. For my height, I have comparatively short legs. I have large feet, size EU48/UK13/US14. KOPS gives me inappropriate knee and ankle angles.

Comment: But KOPS is still a good starting point if you have no idea if you have such morphological aberrations.